# git remove unwanted huge blob files

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

My git repository was huge in size, Hence on analyzing i found that there where couple of huge files accidentally checked-in in a branch and it was removed. But since git maintains its history. I had those files as blobs.

I am able to remove/clear these files and it's historic references using these commands:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' -- --all

rm -Rf .git/refs/original

rm -Rf .git/logs/

git reflog expire --expire=now --all

git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

After above commands my repository has shrunk as expected

But the issue i am facing now is that:
When i push this to remote using:

```
git push --all --force
```

And then try cloning again in a different path to check if changes are reflected, I see the same old huge sized repository.

I tried :

```
git push --all --prune --force
```

All the branches are getting deleted.

I would want only removal of those 2 blob files and its references. Everything else should be intact in remote.

Comment: It's not that _"But since git maintains its history"_ as git doesn't track a file's history, but that the commits which contain those blobs are still "reachable" by a branch, tag, or something else.

Comment: Please spend some time learning to format an SO question. Look at what Joachim Sauer did to format your question, and do that yourself in future. Thanks.